# Solving an ODE with a sign/step function which depends on the time derivative

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, warning-messages, discontinuity

I'm trying to solve a set of ODEs with a Heaviside step function which depends on the sign of the derivative of the function.

This is a simplifying example of what I'm trying to do

```
sol = NDSolve[{
x'[t] == (0.1 x[t]^3 - x[t]) HeavisideTheta[x'[t]], 
x[0] == -2}, {x}, {t, 0, 1}];
Plot[Evaluate[x[t]] /. sol, {t, 0, 10}]
```

I get a lot of errors (`NDSolve::tddisc`, `NDSolve::ntdvdae`, `NDSolve::nlnum`), and it seems that it is not the proper way to work with `NDSolve`.

Can anyone please advise on how to properly use the Heaviside function inside `NDSolve`?

Comment: Use [`UnitStep`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/UnitStep.html) instead.

Comment: `Heaviside -> UnitStep` does not help for me (V11.3). In both cases I get a solution -- is the solution correct? I think so. It's impossible to solve for `x'[t]`, I think, which makes it a DAE, which `NDSolve` can solve.  This equivalent: `NDSolve[{x'[t] == Clip[0.1 x[t]^3 - x[t], {0, Infinity}], x[0] == -1/2}, {x}, {t, 0, 1}]` but emits no warnings or errors.

Comment: Those warnings may or may not mean your results are invalid.  Your code does get results that that need checking, but you do need to use the same range on `x` in `Plot` as you use in `NDSolve`

Comment: You can plot `x'[t]`

Answer (score 4):

I guess your main question is if your solution is correct.  One way to do it:

```
sol = NDSolve[{x'[t] == (0.1 x[t]^3 - x[t]) HeavisideTheta[x'[t]], 
    x[0] == -2}, x[t], {t, 0, 10}] // Flatten;
```

And yes, I get the same warnings you do, although I get one less warning with `UnitStep` but I get the same answer.

```
x[t_] = x[t] /. sol;

Plot[Evaluate[x[t]], {t, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

It satisfies the condition at `x == 0`. And to check if it satisfies the diffeq:

```
Plot[Evaluate[x'[t] - (0.1 x[t]^3 - x[t]) HeavisideTheta[x'[t]]], {t, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Looks reasonably close to me.

Answer (score 3):

As already mentioned by the comments and previous answer, the warning doesn't necessarily mean the result is unreliable. If you still feel uncertain, the following is another way to avoid the warning.

We first solve for $x'(0)$:

```
eq = x'[t] == (0.1 x[t]^3 - x[t]) HeavisideTheta[x'[t]];

newic = Equal @@@ 
  First@Solve[eq /. HeavisideTheta -> UnitStep /. t -> 0 /. x[0] -> -2, x'[0]]

(* {x'[0] == 1.2} *)
```

Then define an approximate `HeavisideTheta`:

```
appro = With[{k = 1000}, ArcTan[k #]/Pi + 1/2 &];
```

Replace the `HeavisideTheta` with `appro` and differentiate the equation once:

```
neweq = D[eq /. HeavisideTheta -> appro, t]
```

And you'll find `NDSolve` can solve the new equation without any warning:

```
sol = NDSolve[{neweq, x[0] == -2, newic}, x, {t, 0, 10}];
Plot[Evaluate[x[t]] /. sol, {t, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> All]
```

The resulting picture looks the same as that in [Bill Watts](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/53121/bill-watts)'s answer so I'd like to omit it here.

Comment: To the downvoter, I am interested in what's wrong with my answer, would you please elaborate. I'm not trying to complain here, I just want to improve my answer if possible.